# How to limit cache folder size

Tags: cache, filecache

My runtime/cache folder is over 200GB in size. Is there a config setting or some way of limiting the size of the folder, rather than the cache duration?

Secondly, what could cause such disk usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a native Craft way to do that.

You could setup a cron job that hit a [plugin's](http://pluginfactory.io) [controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers) and delete items in cache based on size/date created, etc.

My guess is you've got a plugin installed doing some heavy caching. You can try opening the largest cache files (it's all just serialized text data) and see if the type of data gives you a clue to where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks Brad - so on a vanilla Craft install, the cache folder would not grow substantially?

Comment: Nope. Craft only caches for 24 hour by default, so out-of-the-box it should be pretty self-sustaining.